# Battery chart with achartengine adapting code

Tags: java, android, graph, achartengine, battery

I discovered this battery widget in github https://github.com/onlinux/AndroidBatteryWidget. I want create the same graph that there is in the application. The problem is that this is a widget and the things are a little bit differents. The widget has a class https://github.com/onlinux/AndroidBatteryWidget/blob/master/src/fr/free/onlinux/AndroidBatteryWidget/AndroidBatteryWidgetProvider.java with a service `UpdateService` class. Thinking i don't need the widget provider, i take only the service and i created a new class called `UpdateService.java` like this:

```
package com.mypackage.app;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;

public static class UpdateService extends Service {    

public final static String TAG = "Bat";

    //private static final String TAG = AndroidBatteryWidgetProvider.class.getSimpleName();
    public static Boolean debug     = true; 
        BatteryInfo mBI = null;     
        public void updateWidget(Context context, Intent batteryIntent){

            if (debug) Log.i(TAG,"---------- updateWidget");

            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(" HH:mm:ss ");

            RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.androidbatterywidget_layout);

            updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.level, "waiting!");

            final int status = batteryIntent.getIntExtra("status", BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_UNKNOWN);

            final int plugged = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, 0);

            final int level = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);

            updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.level, "" + level + " %" );

            updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.time, formatter.format(new Date()));

            final int temperature = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, -1);

            String tempString= String.format("%.0f°C", new Float(temperature/10));

            if (debug) Log.d(TAG,"BAT:" + tempString + " " + level + "%");

            updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.temperature, tempString );

            final int voltage = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, -1);


       Intent i = new Intent(context, AndroidBatteryActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);

          /*  updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.voltage, "" + voltage + " mV" );


            updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.layout ,

                    PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, 

                            new Intent(context, AndroidBatteryActivity.class),Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));


          ComponentName myComponentName = new ComponentName(context, AndroidBatteryWidgetProvider.class);

            AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

            manager.updateAppWidget(myComponentName, updateViews); */


            //Second, update database in a thread       

            new Thread (new Runnable(){

                public void run(){

                    final Context c=getApplicationContext();

                    DBHelper db = new DBHelper(c);

                    db.record( level, status, plugged );

                    db.deleteOldEntries();

                    db.close();

                    if (debug) Log.i( TAG, "---------- Add record: " + level + " time: "+ Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() );   

                }
            }).start();


        }

        public void  handleCommand(Intent intent){

            if(mBI == null)

            {
                mBI = new BatteryInfo(this);

//              IntentFilter mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();

//              mIntentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
//              registerReceiver(mBI, mIntentFilter);

                // After registering mBI, another update is immediately processed.

                // So, skip double update processing.
                return;

            } 
            //update widget views and database

            updateWidget(getApplicationContext(), intent);

        }

        @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

            handleCommand(intent);            

        }
        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

            if (debug)

                Log.d(TAG, "----------------- onStartCommand");     

            handleCommand(intent);     

            // The service has to be running otherwise the broadcast ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED wont be received anymore

            // thats why it returns START_STICKY
            return START_STICKY;
        }
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {

            super.onDestroy();

            try{                
                if(mBI != null) {

                    if (debug)

                    Log.d(TAG, "----------------- onDestroy: unregisterReceiver(mBI)" );
                    unregisterReceiver(mBI);

                }

            }catch(Exception e)

            {Log.e(TAG, "", e);}

        }
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    }   
}
```

and in my MainActivity i created a button if clicked go to graph, so onclick

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);

        context.startService(intent);
```

Now, what happen is that i can see from the logCat the receiver and the service goes well. But clicking the button in the application nothing happen. The app exit and none activity starts. In the Manifest i wrote

```
<service android:name=".UpdateService" /> 
        <receiver android:name=".BatteryInfo" android:label="BatteryInfo">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED" /> 
        </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".AndroidBatteryActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity" >
        </activity>
```

EDIT: I try to edit a little bit the code and now aadding this part

```
 Intent i = new Intent(context, AndroidBatteryActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
```

Start the Activity AndroidBatteryActivity but is all black and nothing appear. If The AndroidBatteryActivity is this one:

```
public class AndroidBatteryActivity extends Activity {
    public Intent intent ;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        intent = new BatteryChart().execute(this);
           startActivity(intent);
           finish();
    }

    public void myfinish(){
        Log.i("AndroidBatteryActivity", "finish");
        finish();
    }
}
```

and BatteryChart is the class with graph with achartengine.
. How can i adapt the code in mine? How can i start the graph? What i have to change? Thanks

Comment: Why is the achartengine tag added to this question?

Comment: Because the graph was made with achartenigne library. Can you help me to resolve the problem please?

Comment: I suggest you study some AChartEngine examples and start learning from there. Then, you will be able to use the stuff you have learned in your own application. Don't expect anyone to give you all the code you need.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that you may have figured out the answer by now, but anyways here is how to do it :

```
public class MyBatteryReceiver extends Service {

private int batterylevel = 0;
private String batteryStatus = "";


public final static String TAG = "Bat";
public static Boolean debug     = true; 


private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)) {
            batterylevel = intent.getIntExtra("level", 0);



            final int plugged = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, 0);



            final int status = intent.getIntExtra("status",
                    BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_UNKNOWN);
            String strStatus;
            if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING) {
                batteryStatus = "Charging";
            } else if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING) {
                batteryStatus = "Discharging";
            } else if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_NOT_CHARGING) {
                batteryStatus = "Not charging";
            } else if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL) {
                batteryStatus = "Full";
            } else {
                batteryStatus = "";
            }



            new Thread (new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    final Context c=getApplicationContext();
                    DBHelper db = new DBHelper(c);
                    db.record( batterylevel, status, plugged );
                    db.deleteOldEntries();
                    db.close();
                    if (debug) Log.i( TAG, "---------- Add record: " + batterylevel + " time: "+ Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() );    
                }
            }).start();


        }
    }
  };
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
}

}
```

This is your Activity

```
public class AndroidBatteryActivity extends Activity {
public Intent intent ;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_battery_chart);
    intent = new BatteryChart().execute(this);
       startActivity(intent);
       finish();
}

public void myfinish(){
    Log.i("AndroidBatteryActivity", "finish");
    finish();
}
}
```

You need to Start the service from where you prefer

```
    Intent intent = new       
    Intent(YourActivity.this,yourpackagename.MyBatteryReceiver.class);
    YourActivity.this.startService(intent);
```

And this tag in Manifest

```
  <service
        android:name="yourpackagename.MyBatteryReceiver"
        android:label="MyBatteryReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Just change the class name from MyBatteryReceiver to UpdateService for your code